# Use of undeclared type when upgrading to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods, swift2

I am working on a large iOS project, made in Swift 2.3, which are using some private CocoaPods (v. 1.1.1). In one of the pods (made in Objective-C) it has a file called `Enums.h`. This file contains e.g this code:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum){
    MyEnumOne,
    MyEnumTwo
};
```

In my app (Swift 2.3) I have several extensions implemented for enums such as this one. E.g this example:

```
extension MyEnum{
    func name()->String{
        return "some name"
    }
}
```

This is obviously just a small example of what the case really is, but you get the idea.

I am now trying to bump my project to Swift 3.0, and used Xcode's own conversion. My code is now riddled with errors, but that was expected. However, I don't know how to fix this error:

Xcode now marks the first line of the extension-file: `extension MyEnum{` with red error, and says `Use of undeclared type 'MyEnum'`. If I CMD+click the name `MyEnum`, I get directed to the enum inside my cocoapod, exactly where it is declared.. Why does Xcode tell me it's undeclared? This is working perfectly fine in Swift 2.3..

When I updated Swift version and tried to update pods, cocoapods complained that my podfile didn't say `use_frameworks!`, so I added that in. Can this be causing the error?

Edit: 
Even inside the `name()`-function in my extension-file (which now says 'Use of undeclared type'), I can start typing `self.` and get the auto-complete-window stating that `self` is an instance of `MyEnum`, and it shows me the correct values I can use, e.g `rawValue`. Xcode clearly knows about my Enum, but it still says `Use of undeclared type 'MyEnum'`.

Comment: What version of CocoaPods are you using?

Comment: @redent84 1.1.1

Comment: Are you importing the module that contains the enum in your Swift file?

Comment: @redent84 No, I never have.. Is that something I have to do when I use `use_frameworks!`?

Comment: Yes, CocoaPods frameworks are imported as modules in swift code.

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks! This actually fixed the problem, yeah. Feel free to write it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CocoaPods 1.0+, frameworks are compiled as dynamic frameworks and have to be imported to be used.

Try adding an `import` statement to your Swift file. For example, if the CocoaPod is named `MyModule`:

In Swift:

```
import MyModule
```

or in Objective-C

```
@import MyModule;
```

At the top of your extensions file.

Comment: your comment help me as well